# output parameter into label

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, stored-procedures, label

instead of returning my output paremeter value in my stored procedure to my label it returns the default value i set my output parameter to.

why cant i put my output parameter into my text label

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tour", "2365")

cmd.Parameters.Add("@tourname", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters("@tourname").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output


cmd.CommandText = "test"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = conn
conn.Open()
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Dim myTable As DataTable = New DataTable()

myTable.Load(reader)


DropDownList1.DataSource = myTable
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ddate7"
DropDownList1.DataBind()



Label1.Text = cmd.Parameters("@tourname").ToString

conn.Close()
```

Comment: Just to be clear: are you saying that the stored procedure returns a data table *and* an output parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined the @tourname parameter as an output parameter.

```
Dim param as New SqlParameter("tourname", 2356)
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
```

Comment: yeah exactly, i got to this part now but i still cant get it i am getting an String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Comment: Define the size of the output parameter using cmd.Parameters("@tourname").Size, that might help. But would you mind showing your Stored Proc?